# AWS Lambda Access Denied on Pre-Signed CloudFront URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was following the guide from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/deployment.html to create a new Lambda Function over my CloudFront distribution. However, I have an extra requirement to only use the **pre-signed URLs**. The idea is that my service generates the `CloudFront pre-signed URL` and gives that URL to the client to access it. However, client should be able to invoke the Lambda Function on that URL.

For example the following should be possible:

- Service returns the URL `https://dfg565mo4z0svb.cloudfront.net/portrait.jpeg?Expires=1540724061&Signature=VLfwYdHrLM91wzFyOg0S3C6PKkKWghfOiZzt1-ew~gt0HPK~Sap0~5PHVHCEDHgHIQfwb0~oAZQ1igOOiRigzMTQ-ew~uSIR7-dsd~QJlAuceO5f2cDB2hopC5~trEgRTMnQSozPlbrFSwthveVBlZPVI3s2YapZgC7pqZB08IKIYtcXKjRfMPkxgumV5P-~Dj7rK5fdfvLyvTUTxIwrt3WLndOydBjxxUsL-6D-Hkdz8uWi6u59-sg__&Key-Pair-Id=BPKDVBLKFPWSDLIAXN8I`
- The client should be able to invoke Lambda like this: `https://dfg565mo4z0svb.cloudfront.net/fit-in/100x100/portrait.jpeg?Expires=1540724061&Signature=VLfwYdHrLM91wzFyOg0S3C6PKkKWghfOiZzt1-ew~gt0HPK~Sap0~5PHVHCEDHgHIQfwb0~oAZQ1igOOiRigzMTQ-ew~uSIR7-dsd~QJlAuceO5f2cDB2hopC5~trEgRTMnQSozPlbrFSwthveVBlZPVI3s2YapZgC7pqZB08IKIYtcXKjRfMPkxgumV5P-~Dj7rK5fdfvLyvTUTxIwrt3WLndOydBjxxUsL-6D-Hkdz8uWi6u59-sg__&Key-Pair-Id=BPKDVBLKFPWSDLIAXN8I`
   where **/fit-in/100x100/** is the Lambda Function.

All of that works by the default, but if I set the **Restrict Viewer Access
(Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies)** option under Origin Behaviour to **Yes**, then suddenly any call to my Lambda Function returns the **Access Denied** response.

**IAM Policy of the Role that my Lambda Function is using**

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket Policy**

```
    {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EN2PJ6YY7V8EE"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2EM2OLBKAK85T"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I use the presigned URLs with Lambda?

Comment: `dfg565mo4z0svb.cloudfront.net’s server IP address could not be found.` `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`  Did you delete this CloudFront distribution or were these URLs manipulated?

Comment: Manipulated. You need the real url?

Comment: Not necessarily, at this point. I was hoping to see the error XML, but it occurs to me now that these two signed URLs are (a) identical except for the path and (b) canned, not custom.  It is impossible for two canned URLs with different paths (but everything else identical) to both be valid.  It would not be especially secure if the client could use a signed URL to access a resource other than the one for which the signed URL was created.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The XML: <Error> <Code>AccessDenied</Code> <Message>Access denied</Message> </Error>. Actually, only the first one is a signed URL as generated by the service. In the second one I just inserted the "resize" path into it to get the same resource, only resized. What would be the correct way to do it then? This part "/fit-in/{argument}/" is the part that invokes the lambda function, so it should be there in any case, otherwise lambda doesn't work

Comment: The code that is generating a redirect to the second location needs to redirect generate a new CloudFront signed URL.  If the redirect is being generated automatically by S3 redirect rules rather than Lambda code (I haven't looked to see which this example uses) then you'd need to intercept that with an Origin Response trigger and replace it with a signed CloudFront URL in the redirect's `Location` header.  Signed URLs like these authorize access to a single specific path.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot OK, I didn't entirely understand everything that you said there but it seems rather complex. I didn't write the Lambda function, it's some kind of a template (see the URL in my initial question) - I'm not sure if / how I can change it to do whatever it needs to do. Maybe if my service generated the URL with some Custom policy this would work?

Comment: Can you spot if this code does what you described? https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/blob/master/source/image-handler/lambda_function.py

Comment: I don't see it, but this looks like the resize component, and what I was referring to would happen before this runs.  It isn't a Lambda@Edge function, so I'm guessing they must be using S3-generated redirects when images are missing.  The customization necessary to adapt this to work with CloudFront signed URLs is not inordinately complex, but it is not trivial to explain, since that is actually a fairly substantial behavioral change.